# Changing Legend Label Position in VueChartjs

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I am currently working on a project on laravel with vue managing the frontend and I am doing a piechart with vuechartjs and below is the one that I made:

[image]

However, I would like to ask is it possible to move the legend labels down and position them as below?

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you just want them below the doughnut you can put `position: 'bottom'` in the legend config, if you also want it looking like you have in your screenshot you will need a [html legend](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/samples/legend/html.html)